# Finding only big blobs on image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Hello I'm trying to find characters on this image.

This is my image after some preprocessing I recieved this image.

Now I'm trying to do connected component labeling to find blobs. however I get a lot of small blobs too.

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void FindBlobs(const Mat &binary, vector < vector<Point2i> > &blobs);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    Mat img = imread("adaptive.png", 0);

    if(!img.data) {
        cout << "File not found" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("binary");
    namedWindow("labelled");

    Mat output = Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_8UC3);

    Mat binary;
    vector < vector<Point2i > > blobs;

    threshold(img, binary, 0, 1, THRESH_BINARY_INV);


    FindBlobs(binary, blobs);

    // Randomy color the blobs
    for(size_t i=0; i < blobs.size(); i++) {
        unsigned char r = 255 * (rand()/(1.0 + RAND_MAX));
        unsigned char g = 255 * (rand()/(1.0 + RAND_MAX));
        unsigned char b = 255 * (rand()/(1.0 + RAND_MAX));

        for(size_t j=0; j < blobs[i].size(); j++) {
            int x = blobs[i][j].x;
            int y = blobs[i][j].y;
            output.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[0] = b;//Vec3b RGB color order
            output.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[1] = g;
            output.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[2] = r;
        }
    }





    imshow("binary", img);
    imshow("labelled", output);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}

void FindBlobs(const Mat &binary, vector < vector<Point2i> > &blobs)
{
    blobs.clear();



    Mat label_image;
    binary.convertTo(label_image, CV_32SC1);

    int label_count = 2; // starts at 2 because 0,1 are used already

    for(int y=0; y < label_image.rows; y++) {
        int *row = (int*)label_image.ptr(y);
        for(int x=0; x < label_image.cols; x++) {
            if(row[x] != 1) {
                continue;
            }

            Rect rect;

            floodFill(label_image, Point(x,y), label_count, &rect, 0, 0, 4);

            vector <Point2i> blob;

            for(int i=rect.y; i < (rect.y+rect.height); i++) {
                int *row2 = (int*)label_image.ptr(i);
                for(int j=rect.x; j < (rect.x+rect.width); j++) {
                    if(row2[j] != label_count) {
                        continue;
                    }
                        blob.push_back(Point2i(j,i));

                }
            }

            blobs.push_back(blob);

            label_count++;
                    }
    }

}
```

so with this algorithm I recieve blobs

[image]

but when I do

```
if(blobs.size()>50) {
                        blob.push_back(Point2i(j,i));
                    }
```

I recieve black screen. however when I try to

```
 if(blob.size()<50){
                        blob.push_back(Point2i(j,i));
                    }
```

I recieve small blobs what can be the actual problem here ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess you want to store those "big" blobs?

If so, change the following code

```
blobs.push_back(blob);
label_count++;
```

to this:

```
if(blob.size() > 50){
    blobs.push_back(blob);
}
label_count++;
```

And you can receive picture like this:

[image]